# Angular setTimeout Poor Performance

Tags: javascript, angular, performance

I have a component that I need to re-render every time with different `@input` variables because I have some logic implemented in `ngOnInit()`. I am doing this by using following method in parent component with `showSettings` being used to hide and then show the component (with new inputs) after `100ms` delay.

```
private _reloadSettings() {
    this.showSettings = false;
    let a = performance.now();
    setTimeout(() => {
         this.showSettings = true;
         console.log(performance.now() - a);
     }, 100);
    }
```

Everything is working fine except that the re-render takes so much time than expected i.e. it should be around 100ms (or a little over) but actually I am getting like `8000ms` to `10000ms`,
and with each re-render it gets worst.

Comment: why not use a [setter in Input](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#intercept-input-property-changes-with-a-setter) or implements [ngOnChanges](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#intercept-input-property-changes-with-ngonchanges)?

Comment: Why the vote down? Seems a valid question. Perhaps it would be helpful to flesh out what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Try to give us a sense of the scale... 100 components can be few and a lot... it all depends on theirs complexity...

Comment: I have a dynamic form builder with can have any number of form fields. And then I have a settings panel which shows the selected field setting. In my case form builder has 30 fields and a common settings component. when a field is selected I need to reload the settings component with new input data which I'm doing with above function

Answer (score 1):

In other parts of your application, you are doing too much work.

We cannot solve your problem in this case. I would go about looking into [angular change detection](https://angular.io/guide/devtools#profile-your-application).

Other than that, I will show you few things to look for in your codebase:

#### ChangeDetection

You could switch from `ChangeDetection.Default` to `ChangeDetection.OnPush`. This may break parts of your app, but if you would fix those, you will get a big performance boost for all app-wide actions as `setTimeout` is.

In the example above, you are listening to service observable, it might be anything

#### Leaking subscription

```
constructor(myService) {
  myService.data.subscribe(data => {
    this.array = data.array;
  });
}
```

The code above is bad, the subscription is **never** removed, meaning the browser cannot remove the component from memory **AND** the code inside `subscribe` method runs every time. It is fine in this case, but if you were to do some computation inside, it could get bad quickly.

You can fix it by:

1. Subscribing to first emission only.

```
myService.data.pipe(
  take(1),
).subscribe(data => {
  this.array = data.array;
});
```

2. Replacing it with piped observable. This will keep it reactive, but the angular will

```
this.array$ = myService.data.pipe(
  map(data => data.array),
  // Uncomment next line, if the observable is used multiple time
  // shareReply({ ... }), // 
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your guidance, actually I do unsubscribe all the subscriptions in `ngOnDestroy`, but I haven't looked into `ChangeDetection.OnPush` yet and also the code is quite complex with 100s of components are being loaded at once in this specific case.

Comment: It is really hard to judge, but you could also try not to create and destroy them, but rather just hide them via the `hidden` attribute...

Answer (score 0):

Try using queueMicrotask instead of setTimeOut.

```
queueMicrotask(() => {
     this.showSettings = true;
     console.log(performance.now() - a);
 });
```

SetTimeout is a macro task. The call back function provided in setTimeout will be loaded into the call back queue(aka MacroTaskQueue). It waits until the call stack is empty.

The micro task also has similar behavior. But, the microtask gets higher priority, and hence it runs prior to the macro task queue.

[read more about it here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_DOM_API/Microtask_guide)